# Add a file to a ClickOnce already published

Tags: clickonce

Is is possible to add a file to after a ClickOnce has been published? 
I need to add and extra file and I would like to avoid publishing it again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have adopted for now is to use MageUi to regenerate the manifests. 
Even if this is almost the same of publish again from Visual Studio, this allow me to republish without changing anything in the origial solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't add a file without republishing. Add your file, build,  and republish a new version. That's the advantage of using ClickOnce, easy updates.

Comment: Somewhere I read I can add a file an resign with MAGE. The rason I don't want to republish is that I have a code freeze on the release and the build server does the publish on the currento code. I need to add an external library for a specific client, I dont really want to check this in.

Comment: Sure, you can add a file and resign with Mage. But if you don't increment the version number, anyone who has it installed won't get the update. I guess I'm confused by what you mean with "republish".